# Appending rows only if a row's ID value in df1 is also present in df2

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have two dataframes that I want to append to each other. However, I only want to append df2 if the ID variable value is present in df1. This is kind of a merged append, but I am not sure how best to do it. The data looks like such

`str(df1)`

```
ID y  x time
1  15 6  1
2  12 3  1
3  10 8  1
```

`str(df2)`

```
ID y  x time
1  12 3  2
3   8 4  2
4  15 2  2
```

I would like to end up with `df3`:

```
ID y  x time
1  15 6  1
2  12 3  1
3  10 8  1 
1  12 3  2
3   8 4  2
```

`intact_IL <- bind_rows(df1, df2)` gives me everyone in both `df1` and `df2`. Various attempts to use other `dplyr` verbs have not worked for me.

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
intact_IL <- bind_rows(df1, df2 %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID))
```

Comment: This is very helpful @LocoGris! What if I had 5 dataframes set up like this. Does it make sense to name all of them in the `bind_rows` statement, or does it make sense to do two dataframes at a time?

Comment: I can do it, I just need the filter statement after each named `df`. So this works: `intact_IL <- bind_rows(df1, df2 %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID), df3 %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID))`

Answer (score 2):

An option with `base R`

```
rbind(df1, subset(df2, ID %in% df1$ID))
#  ID  y x time
#1  1 15 6    1
#2  2 12 3    1
#3  3 10 8    1
#4  1 12 3    2
#5  3  8 4    2
```